# Is there any alternative way for following query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select, subquery

```
select 
    a.id,
    a.name,
    b.group,
    a.accountno, 
    (
        select ci.cardno 
        from taccount ac, tcardinfo ci 
        where ac.accountno = ci.accountno 
    ) as card_no 
from tstudent a, tgroup b 
where a.id = b.id
```

And how to select more than one field from `(select ci.cardno from taccount ac,tcardinfo ci where ac.accountno = ci.accountno)` or any others way

Please note that the is not a relation in two queries (main and subquery). Sub-query value depends on the data of the main query. Main query is set of data by  joining multiple table and sub-query is also a set of data by joining multiple table

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Why are you not using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

In essence, you are describing a lateral join. This is available in oracle since version 12.

Your query is rather unclear about from which table each column comes from (I made assumptions, that you might need to review), and you seem to be missing a join condition in the subquery (I added question marks in that spot)... But the idea is:

```
select 
    s.id,
    s.name,
    g.group,
    s.accountno, 
    x.*
from tstudent s
inner join tgroup g on g.id = s.id
outer apply (
    select ci.cardno 
    from taccount ac
    inner join tcardinfo ci on ????
    where ac.accountno = s.accountno 
) x
```

You can then return more columns to the subquery, and then will show up in the resultset.

Comment: sorry for incomplete query, please let me complete the query